# Benchmarks for JSON parsers?

Tags: performance, json, parsing, benchmarking

I'm interested in benchmarks for various JSON parsing libraries, ideally, comparing Java and C/C++ implementations.

Java only [benchmarks](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/02/entry_204.html) by the Jackson folks:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For java implementations, there is:

- https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/

which covers all kinds of serialization, including JSON using Jackson, GSON, protostuff.

but unfortunately I have not seen a good comparisons between JSON parsers (and/or generators) on different platforms.

Comment: This is the best I've seen for this kind of benchmark.  Jackson seems fast enough for me at this point.

Comment: Indeed -- if I read benchmark results right (number is nanoseconds per operation, sustained), Jackson would be able to serialize 400,000 small objects per second, read 300,000 which are typically couple of orders of magnitude more than what is needed (same for other fast codecs). So often choice is based on other factors than performance.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure for steraming stax-like API, but for object data binding, gson is smallest and fast for adhoc, jackson is fastest at server side.

http://danielywoo.blogspot.com/2011/04/json-java-libraries-benchmark-jsonlib.html

Comment: Would be interesting to see an update of this, with later/latest versions.